# Where is Bing's Picture of the Day stored on my system?

Tags: kde, desktop-background, plasma

In Kubuntu, I set the desktop background as "Bing's Picture of the Day".

[image: Bing's Picture of the Day]

Some pictures are so good that I desire to store them for further reference.

However, the pictures are not located within `~/Pictures`.

Where are these background images saved?

Comment: Very interesting question! On Kubuntu 18.04, all I can I find a modification to `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`: `[Containments][125][Wallpaper][org.kde.potd][General]`\n
`FillMode=2`\n
`Provider=bing`\n but no actual image anywhere!

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer which mentions an "archive" for Bing wallpapers. You may find it useful.

Comment: And, according to that site, the Trees of many colors is "Rainbow eucalyptus trees along the Hana Highway, Maui, Hawaii (© GlowingEarth/Getty Images Plus)(Bing United States)" from 201912 - United States.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The images are saved in `~/.cache/plasma_engine_potd`.

```
~/.cache/plasma_engine_potd $ ll
total 47492
drwxrwxr-x 2 dkb dkb     4096 Dec 20 15:43 ./
drwxrwxr-x 9 dkb dkb     4096 Dec 20 12:11 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dkb dkb  3540733 Dec 20 15:43 apod
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dkb dkb  3462109 Dec 20 12:11 bing
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dkb dkb 41607252 Dec 20 14:30 wcpotd
~/.cache/plasma_engine_potd $ file *
apod:   PNG image data, 3049 x 1033, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
bing:   PNG image data, 1920 x 1080, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
wcpotd: PNG image data, 7963 x 4886, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Credit: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/5rv5v4/really_like_the_picture_of_the_day_wallpaper/ddbfyol/

---

To use these images, copy them over to the folder in which you store your wallpapers and modify the filenames to have `.png` as the file extension. This step is necessary for the GUI to list them.

---

By the way, a deleted answer by [miharix](https://askubuntu.com/users/432478/miharix) linked to [a site](https://bingwallpaper.anerg.com/) where it's possible to view previous Bing wallpapers along with a brief description of each wallpaper.

Comment: ty, I alternatively tried kinds of predicates of `find` with `-time`, `-size`,  and today's picture name, again failed to locate.

Comment: @Algebra please see the edited answer, Thanks!

Comment: @Algebra see further edit re. having to rename them with `.png`.

Comment: cheers again, btw,  Picture "Tree of many colors"  of today is appealing.

Comment: That location didn't work for me anymore. @abrac answer solved it.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it was in `~/.cache/plasma_engine_potd/`. Possibly they changed the location after an update.

Comment: Yes I agree, on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS (plasma 5.24) the default location is `~/.cache/plasma_engine_potd`

Answer (score 1):

I have never used kubuntu before, but looking at some information about KDE, I would suggest looking in your home directory for one of either of these options

```
$HOME/.local/share/wallpapers

$HOME/.kde/share/wallpapers
```

This link may be helpful

[KDE Location of user wallpapers](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=135265)